# How to generate polygonal thumbs?

Tags: php, image-processing, thumbnails

Is there's a way to generate polygonal thumbnails in PHP? ([ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick), [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library), etc)

Here is an example of what I want to achieve: http://www.area105.com/gallery/shme/thumb1.png

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, and the general process is going to involve using a mask. There was a pretty good write-up by a Stack Overflow user on his blog about making and using a mask. It does not answer your question directly, but should point you in the right direction:

[Creating ‘mask layers’ using PHP GD](http://about.phalacee.com/geek/creating-mask-layers-using-php-gd)

Comment: I can imagine how I would do it without using a mask. Actually I don't think masks help at all.